# How to install Postgresql on Ubuntu from PPA with data-checksums enabled?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

We are currently installing Postgresql from the PostgreSQL apt repository. Is there some way to get "apt-get install postgresql-9.6" to use the --data-checksums option when setting up the cluster?

Or do we need to install Postgresql differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want to install and drop the cluster on Debian and related, you could:

- Install postgresql-common;
- Edit the /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf file to allow the use of the --data-checksums option;
- Install postgresql-9.6.

Answer (score 3):

When you use apt-get, it creates a cluster without data checksum.
All you have to do is to drop the newly created cluster:

```
pg_dropcluster 9.6 main
```

and create a new one with that option

```
pg_createcluster 9.6 <clusterName> <Youroptions (datachecksum for example)>
```

Or you can change the file `/usr/share/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf` to put your data-checksum option there.

Comment: Tx. I tried KookieMonster's 'Install postgresql-common' solution and it worked. I really didn't want to put a 'pg_dropcluster' line in my chef script!